# Is this proof of $\overline{\cup}A_\alpha \subset \cup \overline{A_\alpha}$ valid?

Tags: general-topology

This is a problem from my topology homework:

Let $x \in \overline{\cup}A_\alpha$.  Then for every $U(x)$, $U(x) \cap (\cup A_\alpha) \neq \emptyset \rightarrow U(x) \cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ for some $\alpha \rightarrow x \in \overline{A_\alpha} \rightarrow x \in \cup \overline{A_\alpha}$.

Is the proof valid?  If not, where is the mistake?

As far as I can tell, this proof seems to work. However, the "if not" leads me to believe it's missing at least a small step that I'm overlooking.

I proved the other direction similarly:

Let $x \in \cup \overline{A_\alpha}$.
This implies that $x$ is in at least one of the $A_\alpha$'s, i.e. $\exists \alpha$ such that $x \in \overline{A_\alpha}$. By the definition of closure, this means that $U(x) \cap A_\alpha \neq \emptyset$.  Thus $x \in A_\alpha$, so we may say $x \in \cup A_\alpha$. So  $U(x) \cap (\cup A_\alpha) \neq \emptyset$.  Thus, by the definition of closure, $x \in \overline{\cup}A_\alpha$.

I'm not entirely confident in topology so any feedback or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The claim you are trying to prove is false. Think of a union of one-point subsets in the real line, whose elements are rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake,

$U(x) \cap A_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$ does not imply that $x\in \overline{A_{\alpha}}$.

On the second part, there is also a mistake.

$U(x)\cap A_{\alpha}\not=\emptyset$ doesnot imply that $x\in A_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Oh, I see!  It would be "$\exists y \in U(x) \cap A_\alpha$" but $y$ is not necessarily equal to $x$. In order to save this proof, I would have to ensure that this $y$ would still be in $\cup \overline{A_\alpha}$.

Comment: @Paradigm: Yes. You may take some time to think. Good Luck!

Comment: is it because $A_\alpha \subset \overline{A_\alpha} \subset \cup \overline{A_\alpha}$ (for some $\alpha$) we can say $y \in A_\alpha$ implies $y \in \cup \overline{A_\alpha}$?